# Видимость переменной в java

Tags: java

Задание делаю по этой ссылке: [Занятие 2. Методы](http://math.sgu.ru/sites/chairs/prinf/materials/java/lesson2.htm).
И вот эклипс ругнулся, что переменная x вне зоны видимости! Объясните, пожалуйста, в чём фокус.

```
package MyPack;

public class MyClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {56, 89, 31, 600, 131, 14, 3};
        System.out.println(Matrix());

 }
    static int Matrix() {
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { /*цикл увеличивает значиния массива на 10 процентов */
                x[i] = (x[i]/100)*10 + x[i];
                return x[i];
            }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Здравствуйте. Потому что объявив переменную Х в функции, эта переменная будет теперь доступна только для действий ВНУТРИ этой функции. Для того что бы она была доступна для всех функций класса, нужно объявить её в самом классе, а не в функции, то есть желательно после 
    public class MyClass {

Можно и другим способом передать переменную функции Matrix. Нужно что бы функция Matrix принимала значение. 
Пример:

```
public class MyClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {56, 89, 31, 600, 131, 14, 3};
        System.out.println(Matrix(x));

 }
    static int Matrix(int[] y) {
        for(int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) { /*цикл увеличивает значения массива на 10 процентов */
                y[i] = (y[i]/100)*10 + y[i];
                return y[i];
            }

    }

}
```

П.С. Извните, исправил. :)

Comment: аххах, люблю людей с юморком))
Xy[i] Спасибо)

Comment: хм...чего то на метод ругается

Comment: ну если я правильно понял, то нужно return поставить после цикла for. Выражаясь простым языком (а другим я не умею), функция Matrix не знает про то что в цикле for есть return, и требует поставить ещё return в конце самой функции, так как она в любом случае дожна возвращать значение int.

Answer (score 2):

x является автоматической переменной, то есть объявленной в стеке метода `main()`, даже если метод статический х все равно локальна по отношению к `main()`, вполне логично, что за ее пределами она невидима.

Чтобы она стала видимой ее надо как минимум задекларировать в членах класса.